# Spring for Android

Tags: android, spring

My codes hangs when creating a new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter. I am running on Android 4.1.2. The code is below

```
public void login(String empCode, String password) {
    RestTemplate rt = new RestTemplate();
    MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter jackson = new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter();
    try{
        rt.getMessageConverters().add(jackson);
        rt.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }


    String uri = new String("http://43.68.85.137:8080/cimweb/api/authenticateEmployee");
    Employee employee = new Employee();
    employee.setEmpCode(empCode);
    employee.setPassword(password);
    employee.setAuthenticUser(false);

    Employee returns = rt.postForObject(uri, employee, Employee.class);}
```

and here is the log

> 08-14 16:11:41.250: E/dalvikvm(15517): Could not find class 'org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper', referenced from method org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.
>   08-14 16:11:41.250: W/dalvikvm(15517): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 807 (Lorg/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper;) in Lorg/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter;
>   08-14 16:11:41.250: D/dalvikvm(15517): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x000e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ObjectMapper is not in your classpath.
If you are using Eclipse, right-click in you project and then click on Build path > Configure Build Path...

After that add the necessary jar file.
Make sure that you have this both:

http://www.springsource.org/spring-android

http://jackson.codehaus.org/

Get the latest version of both and add them in your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that the jar containing "ObjectMapper" is not available on the classpath

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have included both Spring core and rest-template libraries to the project.

Answer (score 0):

I ticked the jackson core and mapper and spring-android libraries in the "Order and Export" and it worked

Answer (score 0):

You must add jackson jar files into your project [see this](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDownload). The ObjectMapper is in the databind collection.